# How to update on relevant fields in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, rest

I have a courses table and it has 4 fields namely - id, title, description, deadline.

I want to update only description and deadline, but what i have currently done queries the table by its id and updates all the fields.

How can i update only my description and deadline fields?

```
public function editCourse(Request $request, $id){
         // first check whether a course in that id exists to be updated
         $course = CourseModel::find($id);

         // if there is no such course
         if(is_null($course)){
             return response()->json(["message" => "Record Not found!"],404);
         }
 
         // update the database
         $course->update($request->all());
         return response()->json($course,200);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `save()` method for updating certain field :

```
public function editCourse(Request $request, $id){
         // first check whether a course in that id exists to be updated
         $course = CourseModel::find($id);
         // if there is no such course
         if(is_null($course)){
             return response()->json(["message" => "Record Not found!"],404);
         }
         // update only description and deadline
         $course->description = $request->description;
         $course->deadline = $request->deadline;
         $course->save();
         return response()->json($course,200);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different ways to do this:

1. Use the only method on the $request.

```
    Course::where('id', $id)->update($request->only(['description', 'deadline']));
```

2. You can load up the model, alter its fields manually and save it, like:

```
    $course = CourseModel::find($id);
    $course->description = $request->input('description');
    $course->deadline = $request->input('deadline');
    $course->save();
```

Both of those answers assume you are receiving the fields description and deadline in your request.